# How add simple Jquery and <script> in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js

I has simple `<script>` connect and jquery on page. Here is example: https://codepen.io/TidioSupport/pen/WNePeao

How i can add it correctly to my Vue component?
Because when i try add it, i received:   `Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <script>, as they will not be parsed.` or component not loading.

Hope for your help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your [mounted lifecycle](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html) of Vuejs, you can append the script and then use its function.

Your variables for those scripts can be accessible by `window` global object.

```
mounted() {
      let chatScript = document.createElement('script')
      chatScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://code.tidio.co/fouwfr0cnygz4sj8kttyv0cz1rpaayva.js')
      document.head.appendChild(chatScript)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add it in the head of the html where you are calling your vue app